# Convergence in probability and variance

Tags: variance, convergence

I have a statistic $\widehat{\sigma}$ that depends on data $(X_i,Y_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ with a known distribution, and I want to be able to say that $\widehat{\sigma} - \sigma \xrightarrow{p} 0$ (or $=o_p(1)$). I think I heard my teacher said that if I know the variance of $\widehat{\sigma}$ I can divide $$\frac{\widehat{\sigma}-\sigma}{\text{var}(\widehat{\sigma})}$$ and if $\text{var}(\widehat{\sigma})$ goes to $0$, then I can conclude that $\widehat{\sigma} - \sigma \xrightarrow{p} 0 = o_p(1)$. Is this true? If it is, why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your estimator is unbiased then this is an application of Markov's inequality
$$
P(|\hat{\sigma}-\sigma|>\epsilon) 
\leq 
\dfrac{E(\hat{\sigma}-\sigma)^2}{\epsilon^2} 
=
\dfrac{Var(\hat{\sigma})}{\epsilon^2} 
$$
for any epsilon. Now take the limit.

Comment: Thanks! I see the application of Markov's inequality now. But why should I divide the estimator by the variance?

Comment: Dividing the estimator by the variance is irrelevant.  For *other* purposes people sometimes divide the residual $\hat\sigma-\sigma$ by its *standard error,* which is usually estimated as the *square root* of the variance.  But as this answer shows, even that is irrelevant to your question about convergence in probability.